# Query Corda transaction id of the transaction in which Linear state is consumed

Tags: corda

We have **Linear State** "A". We have two flows one to create state "A" and another to consume the state "A". We have to write a new flow which takes linear id of state "A" as parameter and returns back SingedTransaction id of the transaction in which state "A" is consumed. How can we achieve this in Corda?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this, but I'm not sure whether the transaction that you'll get is the one that created the state, or consumed it; you need to test the below code:

```java
// Get the consumed state by its linearId.
QueryCriteria consumedCriteria = new VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.CONSUMED);
LinearStateQueryCriteria linearCriteria = new LinearStateQueryCriteria()
                    .withExternalId(Collections.singletonList("linearId"));
Page<YourState> results = getServiceHub().getVaultService()
                    .queryBy(YourState.class, consumedCriteria.and(linearCriteria));
        
// Get the transaction by its ID.
// This is a simplified example which assumes that only one result is returned, 
// you might get multiple results if your state was consumed (updated)
// multiple times.    
SecureHash txId = results.getStates().get(0).getRef().getTxhash();
SignedTransaction tx = getServiceHub().getValidatedTransactions().getTransaction(txId);
```

Comment: Thanks Adel for reply. However above example will give the transaction when state is created. We need the transaction when the state is consumed.

Comment: Yeh, I'm not sure how you'd do it the other way around.